# Creating a connected query window from Visual Studio 2012 addin

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins, new-window

I am trying to create a connected query window from Visual Studio 2012 addin.

This is the code i am using:

```
        UIConnectionInfo u = new UIConnectionInfo
        {
            ServerName = serverName,
            ServerType = new Guid(serverType),
            AuthenticationType = authType
        };

        u.AdvancedOptions.Set("DATABASE", databaseName);
        u.AdvancedOptions.Set("PACKET_SIZE", "4096");
        u.AdvancedOptions.Set("CONNECTION_TIMEOUT", "15");
        u.AdvancedOptions.Set("EXEC_TIMEOUT", "0");
        u.AdvancedOptions.Set("ENCRYPT_CONNECTION", "False");
        u.AdvancedOptions.Set("USE_CUSTOM_CONNECTION_COLOR", "False");
        u.AdvancedOptions.Set("CUSTOM_CONNECTION_COLOR", "-986896");

        u.ApplicationName = "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, T-SQL Editor";
        u.UserName = userName;

        if(authType == 1)
        {
            u.Password = password;
        }

        ScriptFactory scriptFactory = ScriptFactory.Instance;
        if(scriptFactory != null)
        {
            scriptFactory.CreateNewBlankScript(ScriptType.Sql, u, null);   
        }
```

All properties in the UIConnectionInfo  are set to the exact values as when you open a query window manualy from Visual Studio 2012.

scriptFactory.FileOpenMode is set to Connected.

I 've even tried to pass an SQLConnection object with opened and closed connection to CreateNewBlankScript ( this helped with Visual Studio 2010 ), but with no result.

Among other assemblies, I have referenced SQLEditors.dll and SQLWorkbench.Interfaces , both 11.0 versions.

Any info would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where UIConnectionInfo and SqlConnection is your connection and queryWindow currently opened window

```
private static void SetConnectionForQueryWindow(Window queryWindow, 
UIConnectionInfo uiConnectionInfo, SqlConnection conn)
    {
        object tempQueryWindow;
        Dictionary<string, object> openedQueryWindows;
        List<Window> temp = new List<Window> { queryWindow };

        openedQueryWindows = GetAllOpenedQueryWindows2012(temp);
        openedQueryWindows.TryGetValue(queryWindow.Document.FullName, out tempQueryWindow);

        if(tempQueryWindow == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Assembly sqlEditor = Assembly.LoadFrom(tempQueryWindow.GetType().Assembly.Location);
        var sqlScriptEditorControl = new SqlEditorTabbedEditorPane(sqlEditor);
        var displaySqlResultsTabControl = new DisplaySqlResultsTabControl2012(tempQueryWindow, sqlScriptEditorControl);

        try
        {
            var connectionStrategyField =
                displaySqlResultsTabControl.QueryExecutorWrapper.QueryExec.GetType()
                    .GetField("_connectionStrategy", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var connectionStrategy = connectionStrategyField.GetValue(displaySqlResultsTabControl.QueryExecutorWrapper.QueryExec);

            var connection = connectionStrategy.GetType()
                .GetField("_connectionInfo", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            connection.SetValue(connectionStrategy, uiConnectionInfo);

            var setDbConn = connectionStrategy.GetType()
                .GetMethod("SetDbConnection", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            object[] parametersArray = { conn };
            setDbConn.Invoke(connectionStrategy, parametersArray);

        }
        catch(NullReferenceException nullReferenceException)
        {

        }
    }

internal static Dictionary<string, object> GetAllOpenedQueryWindows2012(List<Window> windows)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> openedQuerySqlWindows = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach(Window window in windows)
        {
            foreach(Window queryWindow in window.Document.ActiveWindow.Collection)
            {
                if(queryWindow.Object == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if(queryWindow.Object.ToString()
                   != "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.SqlEditor.UI.TabbedEditor.SqlEditorTabbedEditorPane")
                {
                    continue;
                }

                object sqlEditorTabbedEditorPane = queryWindow.Object;
                if(!openedQuerySqlWindows.ContainsKey(queryWindow.Document.FullName))
                {
                    openedQuerySqlWindows.Add(queryWindow.Document.FullName, sqlEditorTabbedEditorPane);
                }
            }
        }

        return openedQuerySqlWindows;
    }
```

where

```
public class SqlEditorTabbedEditorPane
{
    private readonly FieldInfo m_displaySqlResultsControl;

    public SqlEditorTabbedEditorPane(Assembly sqlEditor)
    {
        Type sqlEditorTabbedEditorPane =
            sqlEditor.GetType(
                "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.SqlEditor.UI.TabbedEditor.SqlEditorTabbedEditorPane");
        m_displaySqlResultsControl = sqlEditorTabbedEditorPane.GetField(
            "_resultsControl",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    }

    public FieldInfo DisplaySqlResultsControl
    {
        get
        {
            return this.m_displaySqlResultsControl;
        }
    }
}

public class DisplaySqlResultsTabControl2012
{
    private readonly object m_displaySqlResultsTabControl;

    private readonly QueryExecutor m_queryExecutor;

    public DisplaySqlResultsTabControl2012(
        object scriptEditor,
        SqlEditorTabbedEditorPane sqlScriptEditorControl)
    {
        m_displaySqlResultsTabControl = sqlScriptEditorControl.DisplaySqlResultsControl.GetValue(scriptEditor);
        m_queryExecutor = new QueryExecutor(m_displaySqlResultsTabControl);            
    }

    public DisplaySqlResultsTabControl2012(object scriptEditor, SqlEditorTabbedEditorPane sqlScriptEditorControl)
    {
        m_displaySqlResultsTabControl = sqlScriptEditorControl.DisplaySqlResultsControl.GetValue(scriptEditor);
        m_queryExecutor = new QueryExecutor(m_displaySqlResultsTabControl);
    }

    public object DisplaySqlResultsTabCtr
    {
        get
        {
            return m_displaySqlResultsTabControl;
        }
    }

    public QueryExecutor QueryExecutorWrapper
    {
        get
        {
            return m_queryExecutor;
        }
    }

    public class QueryExecutor
    {
        private readonly object m_queryExecutor;

        public QueryExecutor(object displaySqlResultsTabControl)
        {
            FieldInfo queryExecutor = displaySqlResultsTabControl.GetType()
                .GetField("_queryExecutor", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if(queryExecutor != null)
            {
                this.m_queryExecutor = queryExecutor.GetValue(displaySqlResultsTabControl);
            }
        }

        public object QueryExec
        {
            get
            {
                return m_queryExecutor;
            }
        }
    }        
}
```